# 配列内で特定の値が続いている区間を調べたい

Tags: ruby

`[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]`

とあった時、1の続いている区間を調べたいです。

たとえばこの時、
`2..5, 9..13` ということが知りたいです。

`each_with_index`でflag立ててやる方法は思いつきましたが、何かスマートな方法はありますか？

Comment: `each_with_indexでflag立ててやる方法` のコードを追記するのはいかがでしょうか？それがベターなコードである可能性もあります

Answer (score 5, accepted):

フラグを立てないというと、こんな感じでしょうか。

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0].
  each_with_index.chunk {|x, i| x == 1 }.select {|b, a| b}.
  map {|b, a| [a.first[1], a.last[1]] }
#=> [[2, 5], [9, 13]]
```

Answer (score 2):

`search_ranges`メソッドを作ってみました。
テスト付きのコードはこちらです。

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

def search_ranges(array, target)
  array
    .map.with_index{|obj, index| index if obj == target }
    .chunk{|index| index.nil? }
    .map{|not_target, indicies| indicies.first..indicies.last unless not_target }
    .compact
end

describe 'search_ranges' do
  let(:array) { [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0] }
  it { search_ranges(array, 1).must_equal [2..5, 9..13] }
  it { search_ranges(array, 0).must_equal [0..1, 6..8, 14..15] }
end
```

何をやっているのか分かりづらい場合はこちらのコメント付きのコードをどうぞ。

```
array
  .map.with_index{|obj, index| index if obj == target } # => [nil, nil, 2, 3, 4, 5, nil, nil, nil, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, nil, nil]
  .chunk{|index| index.nil? } # => [[true, [nil, nil]], [false, [2, 3, 4, 5]], [true, [nil, nil, nil]], [false, [9, 10, 11, 12, 13]], [true, [nil, nil]]]
  .map{|not_target, indicies| indicies.first..indicies.last unless not_target } # => [nil, 2..5, nil, 9..13, nil]
  .compact # => [2..5, 9..13]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]

pos = 0
info = {0 => [], 1 => []}
a.each.chunk{|x| x}.each{|v, array|
    info[v] << [pos, pos + array.size - 1]
    pos += array.size
}
p info
```

実行すると次の出力が得られます。

```
{0=>[[0, 1], [6, 8], [14, 15]], 1=>[[2, 5], [9, 13]]}
```

0 が 1..1, 6..8  にあり
1 が 2..5, 9..13 にある　ことが得られています。